# What is the relationship between a step input and an integrator?

Tags: control, control-system

While trying to understand control engineering from first principles I came across the following which I cannot yet explain intuitively or mathematically.

**What is the relationship, between a step input and an integrator?**

**Why are they identical to each other?**

I kept on seeing \$1/s\$ being used to both represent a step input and an integrator.

- The Laplace transform of the unit-step function is \$1/s\$.
- An integrator symbol is also \$1/s\$.

---

**Step Function:**

[image]

**Integrator Block:**

[image]

---

Multiplication by `s` in Frequency (Laplace) domain is differentiation in time.

Dividing by `s` in Frequency (Laplace) domain is equivalent to integration in time.

**Is a step input equivalent to integrating in the time domain, or is it purely coincidental that they both have a spectrum that falls as frequency increases?**

[Why the Laplace transform of the integral is 1/s?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507850/why-the-laplace-transform-of-the-integral-is-1-s)

\$\int\$ in Time Domain = \$ 1/s\$ in Freq Domain

AND

\$\mathscr{L} \{1/s\} = 1\$

---

**EDIT:**

If I am understanding the answers correctly, there is not relationship between a step INPUT and an integrator, but there is a relationship between a step FUNCTION and integrator, as explained below.

Comment: The step response is the integral of the impulse response.

Comment: To answer the question you just added to the bottom: yes.

Comment: And the step input signal is the differential of a ramp input signal LOL.

Comment: Just to cap it off.... The impulse response is \$h\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{H\left(s\right)\}\$, which is the derivative of the step response, \$h \left( t \right)= \frac{ \text{d} }{ \text{d} t }y_{ \gamma } \left( t \right)\$. So: \$y_{ \gamma } \left(t\right)=\int h \left( t \right) \: \text{d}t\$.

Comment: Just let's remind everyone what this question is: **What is the relationship if any, between a step input and an integrator?**. The key word here is **INPUT** and not output.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what happens when an integrator gets a unit impulse as its input. What is the output waveform? What's the Laplace transform of a unit impulse?

Comment: When an integrator gets a unit impulse, according to my simulink the output rises from 0 to 1 over a 1 second duration and then remains constant at 1. The Laplace transform of a unit impulse is 1, but I don't intuitively see any connection.

Comment: @Rrz0r. Are you sure that isn't a one *sample* duration?

Comment: No I am not sure about this, I am using a discrete impulse block on Simulink.

Comment: A discrete impulse is different from a really-o truly-o Dirac delta functional, which is an "impulse" in continuous-time signal processing.  \$\delta(t)\$ has no width, is zero everywhere except for \$t=0\$, and \$\int_{0^-}^{0^+} \delta(t) dt = 1\$.  If you haven't seen it before and it's boggling your mind -- relax, you have company.

Comment: Simulink (and Matlab, for that matter) probably does not have a Dirac impulse function available.  The Dirac delta functional is a little bit of mathmagic that applies to doing symbolic computation related to linear systems; it's not something that you can simulate directly.  You can *approximate* it with a positive-going rectangular pulse that's \$\epsilon\$ seconds wide and \$1/\epsilon\$ tall, and then choose an \$\epsilon\$ significantly smaller than any of your system's time constants.  I wouldn't advise trying -- just do the symbolic math.

Comment: @TimWescott, I'm actually getting familiar with the Dirac delta function. But still, I dont get how this has to do with the relationship between a step input and an integrator, even though it seems to be deeply involved.. somehow.

Comment: If you do the math to answer the question "what is the impulse response of an integrator?" then you will be the width of a Dirac impulse away from understanding the answer to your question.

Comment: The Dirac impulse is indeed the relationship. This contradicts the answer of Andy aka does it not?

Comment: @Rrz0 I never let contradicting Andy stand in the way of my posting the correct answer.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, When an integrator gets a unit impulse as it's input, the output is a step function. Since the Laplace function of a unit impulse is `1`, then to get to the step function `1/s`, the unit impulse must be divided by `s` which also results to `1/s`, which is why the integrator's symbol is `1/s`.

Comment: @Neil_UK you are not contradicting me. The question asks about a step input (RTFQ) and your answer is about a step response i.e. the output from an integrator when fed with a unit impulse INPUT. The fact that you haven't addressed the question at all appears to be lost on folk.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> What is the relationship if any, between a step **INPUT** and an
>   integrator?

For the purpose of reminding folk what this question is about I have edited the quote above (from the OP) to highlight the word **INPUT**. Folk seem to be reading response (or output) instead and that is somewhat baffling.

Consider this:

- White noise has a spectrum of "x" at all frequencies i.e. it is spectrally flat
- A perfect amplifier with a gain of "x" has a transfer function of "x" at all frequencies.

Does anyone get in a muddle about this? Do they have a relationship?

So, a unit step has a spectrum that falls as frequency increases and an integrator also has a transfer function that happens to do the same. Should this be a big deal?

And a final reminder about the question asked: -

Comment: While it's true that there doesn't have to be a relationship between two things, it can often be enlightening to consider why two things look similar. I don't disagree with your answer, but I think it might be too dismissive; this is, after all, the type of question that leads to great insight in mathematics. Honestly, after reading your answer, now I find myself thinking about whether there _is_ some mathematical relationship between a perfect amplifier and white noise.

Comment: @Felthry I insist you make this an answer!!

Comment: I would, but it doesn't answer the question! And I'm not currently able to write it up into a form that does so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It feels as though I am _still_ missing something fundamental, which I can't yet explain. It could be because I don't fully understand your last sentence. @Felthry I think that would actually be very helpful.

Comment: @Andyaka if there really is no relationship then is the thought process presented above incorrect?Am I going off on a tangent?

Comment: @Rrz0 a step input is just exactly what it is; a particular type of input used in the analysis of things. An integrator is not an input; it is a transfer function and may have any particular input signal applied to it. There is no particular relationship between an input signal and a transfer function, it is purely coincidental as I explained with the example of white noise and a perfect amplifier.